# How to determine the distance between Olympus Mons and Valles Marineris?

Tags: mars, planetary-science, geology

How can I determine the distance between Olympus Mons and the closest point of Valles Marineris?

What tools are available to the general public for these kinds of queries?

Comment: Did you try measuring this on a map of Mars?

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys As you must certainly know, one can not simply measure the great-circle distance between two points on a sphere by picking up *any random 2D projection map* and laying a ruler on it. While I've edited the question accordingly, I think your comment is misleading and trivializes a new user's fist question.

Comment: Also GoogleEarth allows to switch to Mars or Moon, and then use the ruler tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of those tools is [this calculator on the NASA website](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/special/getMileage.action).

Let's see what it gives us here:

- [Olympus Mons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympus_Mons) is at [18.65° N, 226.2° E](https://geohack.toolforge.org/geohack.php?pagename=Olympus_Mons&params=18_39_N_226_12_E_globe:mars_type:landmark)
- The westernmost point of the [Valles Marineris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valles_Marineris#Regions_of_Valles_Marineris) is [Noctis Labyrinthus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noctis_Labyrinthus), which is at [7° S, 102.2° W](https://geohack.toolforge.org/geohack.php?pagename=Noctis_Labyrinthus&params=7.0_S_102.2_W_globe:mars_type:landmark)

According to the calculator, the distance is **2387.8 km.**

(Note that in order for the lines on the map to match, you need to enter Point 1 as 18.65, -226.2 and Point 2 as -7, 102.2, so the longitudes are the negatives of what is mentioned in the instructions):

[image]

Depending on which point you choose in the Noctis Labyrinthus, the distance may be a bit less or more.

Comment: Related: [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula) just substitute Mars radius (3389.5) where Earth radius (6371) is given.

Answer (score 2):

There's some ambiguity about whether [Noctis Labyrinthus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noctis_Labyrinthus) is part of [Valles Marineris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valles_Marineris).
According to Wikipedia it is part of the Valles Marineris *system*, but it also says that Noctis Labyrinthus is a region between Valles Marineris and the [Tharsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tharsis) upland.
Anyway, [Mars Trek](https://trek.nasa.gov/mars/) is an excellent tool to determine distances and elevations on Mars.
Press the **"Skip Tutorial"** button and zoom in once, and you already see Olympus Mons at the left with the other three shield volcanoes.
At the right corner below you see the latitude and longitude values and with that you can find the western edge of Valles Marineris.
Then press on the menu button in the upper right corner and choose the **"Calculate Elevation Profile"**.
Then select **"Line"** and press down on Olympus Mons and let go on the western edge of Valles Marineris.
Then the distance is shown and if you press the **"Submit"** button you get the elevation profile from Olympus Mons to Valles Marineris.

If you choose the most north-western edge  of the **canyon** of Valles Marineris the distance will be about 2888 km.